# What does $\prod\limits_{k=-2}^{11}(15-3k)$ mean--and how might I compute it?

Tags: notation, terminology

$$\prod_{k=-2}^{11}(15-3k)=\;?$$

I'm new to this and have not seen this notation before. Can anyone explain to me what this is called and how to solve or compute it?

Comment: $Σ$ (the greek letter of $S$) for "S"um, $Π$ (the greek letter $P$) for "P"roduct and ... V for ...

Comment: @kahen That title edit just changed the nature of the question rather significantly...

Comment: Possibly. But at least the question makes *sense* now. And I have no clue how anyone could think that OP's problem has anything to do with calculus.

Comment: @crash thanks. You really explained well

Comment: @kahen I completely agree about the "calculus" comment, but I imagine this notation was encountered in a calculus context. I'll re-edit the title to try to make it more appropriate in regards to this question specifically.

Comment: @Mathxx Please see the new but minor edit to my answer (thanks to dberm22); in my expansion for $(3)$, I accidentally indicated that I was starting at $k=1$ when I was really starting at $k=-2$. [This doesn't really change anything for the answer, but you should be aware of it.]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note on notation:** As others have mentioned, the $\prod$ symbol stands for "product" and is actually typeset by `$\prod$`; similarly, the $\sum$ symbol stands for "sum" and is actually typeset by `$\sum$`. You may have seen the $\Sigma$-notation before, but let's consider the $\Pi$-notation because that's what you are really interested in here. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Products_of_sequences) on $\Pi$-notation is good and should get you started. They give the example
$$
\prod_{k=1}^4 k = 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4 = 24.\tag{1}
$$
Can you see how that worked? You multiply everything together for the values $k=1,2,3,4$. Similarly, for $\prod_{k=1}^n k$, you would multiply everything together for the values $k=1,2,\ldots,n$. So let's consider a more interesting example:
$$
\prod_{k=1}^4 (k+2) = \underbrace{(\color{red}{1}+2)}_{\color{red}{k\,=\,1}}\cdot\underbrace{(\color{red}{2}+2)}_{\color{red}{k\,=\,2}}\cdot\underbrace{(\color{red}{3}+2)}_{\color{red}{k\,=\,3}}\cdot\underbrace{(\color{red}{4}+2)}_{\color{red}{k\,=\,4}} = 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6 = 360.\tag{2}
$$
Make sense? Now let's consider **your** problem.

**Your problem:**
We are tasked with computing
$$
\prod_{k=-2}^{11} (15-3k).
$$
Based on what you saw in $(1)$ and $(2)$, do you see how you might compute this? You can write out *all* of the terms, but this proves to be a fruitless endeavor as other answerers have pointed out. Here's why:
$$
\prod_{k=-2}^{11} (15-3k) = \underbrace{[15-(-6)]}_{k\,=\,-2}\cdot\underbrace{[15-(-3)]}_{k\,=\,-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot\color{red}{\underbrace{\overbrace{(15-15)}^{\color{blue}{=\;0}}}_{k\,=\,5}}\cdot\ldots\cdot\underbrace{(15-33)}_{k\,=\,11}.\tag{3}
$$
Simplifying $(3)$ a bit, you can see that
$$
\prod_{k=-2}^{11} (15-3k) = 21\cdot 18\cdot\ldots\cdot\color{red}{0}\cdot\ldots\cdot -18=0
$$
because any number multiplied by zero is zero. This is what Jasper Loy's answer immediately noted. Do you see it now?

Comment: In stepping through his problem, in the expansion, you show that the sequence starts at k=1, which it should be k=-2. The math is correct, but the comments are not. Look right above "that" in "Simplifying (3) a bit, you can see that"

Comment: @dberm22 I don't think you are reading my answer correctly; the products considered in $(1), (2)$, and $(3)$ are all completely different products.

Comment: yes, I know. but [15 - (-6)] is for k=-2, not k=1, as -6 = 3*-2.

Comment: @dberm22 The product in $(3)$ **starts** at $k=-2$, not $k=1$.

Comment: I'm aware of that. Look right above "that" in "Simplifying (3) a bit, you can see that". You have k=1, where it should be k=-2. just the comment, not the actual math.

Comment: @dberm22 How does it look now?

Comment: Looks good. Great answer.

Comment: @dberm22 Thanks and *good eyes*. A brain fart is inevitable every now and again I suppose :( Thanks a lot for catching that subtle error!

Answer (score 6):

When $k=5$, $15-3k=0$, so the product is $0$.

Comment: Nice observation but I think OP is looking for more than that. I didn't downvote (I see the person rescinded their downvote) but consider explaining the notation and how you came to your answer.

Comment: thank you for changing your user name. i used to get pings fem others intended for you.

Answer (score 3):

The symbol $\prod$ indicates a product, in a similar fashion as the $\sum$ for sums. In this case, the formula works out as $$(15 - 3(-2)) \cdot (15 - 3(-1)) \cdot (15 - (3\cdot0)) ...$$

Comment: Where did you get the `(15 - 3)(-1))` from?

Comment: Do you mean (15 - 3(-1))? That's when k = -1.

Comment: Sorry I'm learning too! When will `k = -1` I thought it was `-2`?

Comment: $-2$ is just the starting value. Do you see that number 11 above the $\prod$? That means that you have to multiply $(15 - 3k)$ for all integer values of $k$, from $-2$ to $11$.

Comment: D - Oh. So if `k = 1` and the number above the product was `5` then you would multiply $(15 - 3k)$ for all integer values from 1 to 5?

Comment: Exactly: it would be $(15 - 3) \cdot (15 - 6)...$

Answer (score 3):

just as we write $$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots + a_{10} = \sum_{j=1}^{10}a_j,$$  the product is written as $$a_1a_2\cdots a_{10} = \prod_{j=1}^{10} a_j $$

so $$\prod_{k = -2}^{11}(15-3k) = 21 \times 18 \times\cdots\times 0 \cdots(-18) = 0 $$

Answer (score 1):

$$\prod_{k=-2}^{11}(15-3k)=21\cdot18\cdot15\cdot12\cdot9\cdot6\cdot3\cdot0\cdot....\cdot(-18)=0$$